# How to display an array to the user

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to display the contents of an ordered array in something like a JTextField.

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    this.textField.setText(array[i]);
}
```

This won't work for two reasons. The first minor reason: if the array length is 4 then jtextfield is getting it's value reset 4 times rather than appending each element onto the last.
Second reason: The JTextField only takes strings. I can't find anything I can use in Swing that will let me display integers to the user. Any help?

Answer (score 8):

### Quick & Dirty Answer

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    this.myJTextField.setText(this.myJTextField.getText() + ", " + array[i]);
}
```

### Correct Way

First, calling a member variable `JTextField` probably isn't wise. Since the class is already called like that, it will confuse readers. Naming conventions in Java state member variables are like `myTextField` for example. (note: original question changed).

#### User defined format

Note you can convert any number to a string by simply doing `"" + number` too. If you have many strings, consider using a string builder, as that's faster and won't update the GUI element multiple times: (also fixes the initial `", "` before the first item, which happens above)

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    builder.append(array[i]));
    if(i + 1 != array.length) 
        builder.append(", ");
}
this.myJTextField.setText(builder.toString());
```

#### Canonical array representation

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
this.myJTextField.setText(Arrays.toString(array));
```

It will look like `[1, 4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all those integers into a string the then present that value in the textfield.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( int i : array ) {  // <-- alternative way to iterate the array
     sb.append( i );
     sb.append( ", " );
}

sb.delete(sb.length()-2, sb.length()-1); // trim the extra ","
textField.setText( sb.toString() );
```

You can use a JTextArea instead of the textfield too.

Comment: You'll need to trim off the extra ", " at the end.

Comment: Ahh yeap.. 1,2,3,4, => 1,2,3,4